# ICS ROM for Samsung Galaxy Y

Tags: custom-roms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

I am looking for a custom rom for my Samsung Galaxy Y S5360.

I want to install Android 4.0 ICS, but most of the custom ROM's I find are actually ICS themed, meaning they just have the ICS look and feel but the actual OS is still Gingerbread. I want ICS so that I can install apps that are incompatible with Gingerbread.

Please give me a link to a bug-free ICS ROM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at forum's such as [XDA-Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com), where you will find many ROM developers, and a forum for your device.

Looking at your device however, it only has an Armv6 processor. ICS only supports the Armv7 architecture, so ICS will not be compatible for your device, unless someone ports it to your device which would be difficult, but not impossible as shown by the ICS ROM by mikegapinski for the LG GT540 at the above forum.